# InputStream.read(byte[] b) blocked loop, don't return EOF(-1)

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, kotlin

I have small problem with inputStream.read() method while trying to receive message via bluetooth from my arduino. I'm trying to get -1 byte while EOF. The problem is that, i don't get it.

InputStream.read() get block after last data receive, and wait for more data. As 
far I know right now, It works properly.

I made some research and find you that, I can't get EOF(-1), until server(arduino) close his stream(outputstream?).
I would like to know that I'm going in the right direction of understanding this, and if yes, so what if I close the stream from arduino, my loop from code below will work?

Maybe, better is to add special sign, at the end of the data?

How you guys solve problem like that? :)

```
     override fun run() {
        Log.d(TAG, getLogString("BEGIN connected thread.", device))
        name = device.name + device.address
        connected = true

        val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
        var bytes: Int

        while (connected) {
            try {
                bytes = inputStream!!.read(buffer)

                if (bytes = -1) {
                   //Don't work
                   Log.d(TAG,"EOF")
                }
                val message = String(buffer, 0, bytes)
                handler.obtainMessage(BluetoothApi.MESSAGE_READ, message).sendToTarget()

                // For debug purposes.
                Log.d(TAG, getLogString("Received message: $message", device))

            } catch (e: IOException) {
                Log.e(TAG, getLogString("Disconnected.", device), e)
                connectionLost()
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This just looks like some incorrect logic here.  Q: What is setting `connected` to `false`?  Without that, this is just an infinite loop.  (I see a `connectionLost()` call, but that only happens if there is an `IOException` ... not in the case where you reached the end of the stream. ) Q: What is *testing* to see if the value of `bytes` is `-1`?

Comment: This should be infinite loop, `connected` to `false` is set when I lost connection to device. Any way this loop dosen't work, becouse It's blocked after inputStream.read(). `bytes` is never -1. That is the problem.

Comment: The reason that `read()` blocks is that the remote end has stopped writing, but has not closed the connection.   The remote end should indicate that it has finished by closing.   When you have fixed that, you can deal with the infinite loop problem.